# Site which shows algos in popular languages?

Tags: algorithm, sites

Is there a site like "language shootout"'s (shootout.alioth.debian.org and dada.perl.it/shootout/), which show how to do simple/advanced things in different languages? I.e. how to use hashes in different languages, how to sort, how to write classes, how to connect to sites, etc.. Well, those two above ARE in fact examples of what I'd like to find, but they have VERY limited selection of algos. Any other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many such sites. See [RosettaCode::Similar_Sites](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Help:Similar_Sites)

Answer (score 4):

I like [LiteratePrograms](http://en.literateprograms.org).